# ExternalInterface.call in Opera doesn't perform

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

ExternalInterface.call in Opera (ver. 12.01) doesn't perform.
I'm using SWFObject.

In my index.php file in head-section:

`swfobject.embedSWF("example.swf", "flash", "1", "1", "10.0.0");`

JavaScript function in body:

```
function ready() {
    alert();
}
```

Code in ActionScript 3:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call('ready');
}
```

In Google Chrome all works fine. 
What may cause the problem in Opera?

Even Internet Explorer 7 works properly with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the JavaScript `ready` method is unavailable when the Flash first attempts to call it. The Adobe documentation recommends polling the JavaScript until you get a result (see the `ExternalInterface.as` example [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)).

You could test the theory quickly with something like the following:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    // Poll JavaScript.ready method until we get a result
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (ExternalInterface.call('ready')) {
            trace("JavaScript is ready");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

Also, `JavaScript.alert` is a fairly intrusive method of debugging. Try using `console.log` instead:

```
function ready() {
    console.log("JavaScript.ready method fired");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opera has issues with ExternalInterface calling the alert function on js side. Avoid calling it.