# Opera does not call Flash's ExternalInterface.callback() function inside js callback called by flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript, opera, flash

I'm new to Flash ActionScript. I've a flash audio recorder (modified [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery)) that records audio in WAV format and I've added support for MP3 encoding. The recorder exports some public functions for JS using ExternalInterface.callback() and also calls JS callbacks using ExternalInterface.call() from flash container (website). When a flash exported function is called from JS to start recording/encoding/other that function from flash also calls JS callback event handler for event like- recording_started, recording_stopped, encoding_started, encoding_ended etc. It works fine in IE, FF, Chrome but not in Opera.

I've used it in a web project as follows-

-> Recording time is maximum 2 min and recording stops when user stops it (button) or when time limit reached. And for both conditions, 'recording_stopped' event is triggered and inside that event handler, mp3 encode function is called (a flash exported function).

-> Here, JS event handler is called by flash and which in tern calls a flash exported function.

The problem is, in opera, the exported flash function is not called inside the handler. If the function is called at the end of the handler, all codes above the function are executed but not that function and if I place the function at the beginning of the handler, the codes below it are not executed. And no JS error is shown in the console. But, if I called it from a JS function which is not a callback event handler for flash, the function is executed fine.

I've tested it on two different computers with Opera versions 11.51 & 12.15 and flash player versions 11.3, 11.6 & 11.7.

My opera version is 12.15 and flash player version is 11.7 (for all browsers).

Why is it happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExternalInterface.call in Opera doesn't perform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026394/externalinterface-call-in-opera-doesnt-perform)

Comment: related discussion: http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=264589

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Two links you stated are not similar to my case. For first, the callbacks is called by flash except it does not execute its exported function inside the callback. For second, the problem is not similar to mine.

Comment: I think the duplicated question fits your question, as Opera does not perform `ExternalInterface.call` at all. Any function call via this ActionScript method in Opera will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to ignore this problem while typing this question. Solution is, instead of calling the flash exported function directly from the event handler, I'm calling it using JS's window.setTimeout() function like -

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    if($.jRecorder.encodeToMp3())
      isEncoding = true;                
}, 0);
```

I'm not sure why it is happening. @Raptor commented a reason on the question and it can be that reason or else.